# React Native screen designing and component ordering

Tags: react-native

I guess, I couldn't learn React-Native properly. I've been trying to learn for a week. (and I've been trying to move a PhoneGap project into React-Native. Completely different two worlds!)

I've seen several samples that use a Drawer menu. Most of samples use a Drawer component as a top component of application. And the drawer component may be developed by a free developer or official React-Native component. Flexibility..

*So, which components should I use and which order in my project to do like the screen below **?** (roughly)*

The order of the below components are right?

```
<View 
  <Drawer
    <View    // MAIN CONTAINER FOR THE FIRST PAGE
      <View
        <TextInput  // USED FOR TO SEARCH TEXT (My music)
        <Button     // USED FOR TO SEARCH (Magnifying Glass)
        <View       // USED FOR THE REST OF THE PAGE INCLUDES CARD COMPONENTS
```

[image]

Comment: I think you want to customise navigation bar. Try this one and hope it works.https://github.com/react-native-fellowship/react-native-navbar

Comment: @Phyo , I'd seen this component. So, I can create top part of every page  using this component and Left button would be side menu button, Middle part would be as a InputText and Right part would be magnifying glass. I think it makes sense. I think you can copy-paste that as an answer. Then I can give reputation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want to customise navigation bar. Try this one and hope it works.

[React-Native-Navbar](https://github.com/react-native-fellowship/react-native-navbar)